# Android: AsyncTask takes long time to go from return in doInBackground to start of postExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am running an `AsyncTask` in a fragment and its taking a long time (1-3 seconds) to go from the return statement in `doInBackground` to the first line of `postExecute`.

I set up logs which led me to this conclusion:

- 09-07 20:26:15.496 ﹕ Entered doInBackground of myAsyncTask
- 09-07 **20:26:15.496** ﹕ Finished doInBackground of myAsyncTask
- 09-07 **20:26:18.524** ﹕ Entered postExecute of myAsyncTask
- 09-07 20:26:18.525 ﹕ Finished postExecute of myAsyncTask

I don't see why it is taking so long to start `postExecute`. In `doInBackground` I'm just returning null, so the passing of that parameter shouldn't be time consuming. I don't understand why it is taking so long.

Can someone clarify this for me? Why would it take so long to enter `postExecute` from the return line of `doInBackground`?

Code of the AsyncTask below:

```
 public class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.d("AnswerTabFragment", "Entered preExecute of UpdateTask");

        mRefreshWrapper.setRefreshing(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
        Log.d("AnswerTabFragment", "Entered postExecute of UpdateTask");

        mRefreshWrapper.setRefreshing(false);
        if(mAnswers.isEmpty()){
            mHeaderTextView.setText("No Answers");
            mHeaderTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            mHeaderTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        Log.d("AnswerTabFragment", "Finished postExecute of UpdateTask");

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params  ) {
        Log.d("AnswerTabFragment", "Entered doInBackground of UpdateTask");

        if(u == Application.qollegeCache.currentUser){
            mAnswers.clear();
            mAnswers.addAll(Application.qollegeCache.myAnswers);

        }
        else{
            try {
                Answer.unpinAll(u.getObjectId() + "Answers");

                mAnswers.addAll(Answer.getQuery()
                        .whereEqualTo(Constants.kQollegeAnswerPostedByKey, u)
                        .orderByDescending(Constants.kQollegeQuestionCreatedAtKey)
                        .find());

                Answer.pinAllInBackground(u.getObjectId() + "Answers", mAnswers);


            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        Log.d("AnswerTabFragment", "Finished doInBackground of UpdateTask");

        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: How much time taken by `Answer.pinAllInBackground(u.getObjectId() + "Answers", mAnswers);` line?

Comment: Log statements are not guaranteed to be displayed exactly when they are called.

Comment: it could be an indication that you ui thread is overloaded and so things take time to be executed when enqueued to it.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Each time I've tested it, the user has always been the currentUser, so that code has never been called.

Comment: And are you getting same results each time you run this code?

Comment: @ColinGillespie That maybe, but I've run this multitudes of times, and every time the only log statements with a large time difference are between the end of doInBackground and the start of postExecute.

Comment: @njzk2 is there a way for me to test if the ui thread is indeed overloaded?

Comment: It is because they are coming from multiple threads. I have an app that queries online resources and displays them. The log statement is called before I tell the app to display the data. The data shows up in the app up to 5 seconds before log statement outputs.

Comment: @Darpan Yes the results are consistent with a large time difference between the end of doInBackground and the start of onPostExecute

Comment: Determine System.millis() -or whatever it is called- at end of doInBackground and again at start of onPostExecute. Compare.